# Best way to change color of a text depending on a value of another string using angular

Tags: json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm using angular js and I have a problem and I have tried many ways and googled almost everything related but can't get it to work. I'm displaying "Name" and "Status" in a table which come from a json file. I want to change the color of the "Name" depending on what number (string) is in the "status" column. Like if "status" is -1 the "name" should be red. What is the best way to do this. I'm guessing it should be done inside the controller where i'm getting the json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-class for it.

For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array" ng-class="{redClass : item.status == -1}">
   {{item.name}}
</div>

.redClass {
   color: red
}
```

This is working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4159/) for this example.

Also please see more about [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

Comment: @user3513207, you are welcome, but if you have got right answer, mark it as best or useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).
A common way of usage is `ng-class="{ classname: if condition results to true, class is applied }`

So what you should do, most probably, is something like:

```
  <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{ red:item.status == 1, green: item.status == 3, blue: item.status == 4 }" >
   {item.name}}
  </li>
```